# Kendo grid with X-editable?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, x-editable

I am trying to use x-editable plugin

http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6">

        <table id="rowSelection">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="make">Car Make</th>
                        <th data-field="model">Car Model</th>
                        <th data-field="year">Year</th>
                        <th data-field="category">Category</th>
                        <th data-field="airconditioner">Air Conditioner</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Volvo</td>
                        <td>S60</td>
                        <td>2010</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Audi</td>
                        <td>A4</td>
                        <td>2002</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BMW</td>
                        <td>535d</td>
                        <td>2006</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BMW</td>
                        <td>320d</td>
                        <td>2006</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>No</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>VW</td>
                        <td>Passat</td>
                        <td>2007</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>No</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>VW</td>
                        <td>Passat</td>
                        <td>2008</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Peugeot</td>
                        <td>407</td>
                        <td>2006</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Honda</td>
                        <td>Accord</td>
                        <td>2008</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>No</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Alfa Romeo</td>
                        <td>159</td>
                        <td>2008</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>No</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nissan</td>
                        <td>Almera</td>
                        <td>2001</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mitsubishi</td>
                        <td>Lancer</td>
                        <td>2008</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Opel</td>
                        <td>Vectra</td>
                        <td>2008</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Toyota</td>
                        <td>Avensis</td>
                        <td>2006</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>No</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Toyota</td>
                        <td>Avensis</td>
                        <td>2008</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Toyota</td>
                        <td>Avensis</td>
                        <td>2008</td>
                        <td>Saloon</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Audi</td>
                        <td>Q7</td>
                        <td>2007</td>
                        <td>SUV</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hyundai</td>
                        <td>Santa Fe</td>
                        <td>2012</td>
                        <td>SUV</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hyundai</td>
                        <td>Santa Fe</td>
                        <td>2013</td>
                        <td>SUV</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nissan</td>
                        <td>Qashqai</td>
                        <td>2007</td>
                        <td>SUV</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mercedez</td>
                        <td>B Class</td>
                        <td>2007</td>
                        <td>Hatchback</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lancia</td>
                        <td>Ypsilon</td>
                        <td>2006</td>
                        <td>Hatchback</td>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table> 

      </div>
```

With Kendo grid template and i got problem, something strange happen to table when click on edit row?
entire table shift left, here is example of working fiddle what i have problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/LozkL2cx/

On fiddle x-editable does not even fire up i dont know why?

**JS**

```
  $("#rowSelection").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    pageSize: 6
                },
                sortable: {
                    mode: "single",
                    allowUnsort: false
                },
                pageable: {
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                scrollable: false,
                navigatable: true,
            });





    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';     

    //make username editable
    $('td').editable();
```

Comment: I'm curious. Why are you using another third-party plug-in when Kendo UI Grid already natively supports inline, popup, and batch editing?

Comment: yes, it but it does not have styling like this, it has inline, and popup in modal :(

Answer (score 0):

cell shifts left because x-editable inject a Div after closing `</td>`

I've solved this way, maybe there's a better one

```
<td><div class="edit">1</div></td>

$('.edit').editable();
```

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LozkL2cx/5/)